# Particular solution help for a 2nd order linear non-homogeneous differential equation

Tags: linear-algebra

My concern is that there's a trick I'm unaware of, my mathematics is all wrong, or the problem itself is wrong.

When solving:

$$ y''-3y'+2y=e^{2x}$$

The auxiliary and complementary solutions are fine.

When it comes to doing the particular solution for $e^{2x}$, that's where things get a little messy.

For a particular solution, $Y_{p}$, we set a coefficient $A$, s.t.

$$ Y_{p} = Ae^{2x} $$

Taking the derivatives, we get:

$$ Y'_{p} = 2Ae^{2x} $$
$$ Y''_{p} = 4Ae^{2x} $$

As per the solution procedure, we apply these to the original equation to evaluate $A$:

$$ 4Ae^{2x}-3(2Ae^{2x})+2(Ae^{2x}) = e^{2x} $$

...which results in:

$$ 0 = e^{2x} $$

...which is not possible right?

If that is the case, what does one do?

Comment: You could try $Y_p=xAe^{2x}$ instead

Comment: When the right side is a solution of the homogeneous equation, you can't expect a constant multiple of it to be a solution of the non-homogeneous equation as well.  As @cist said, the next thing to try is multiplying the trial solution by $x$.

Comment: @ctst: Didn't know you could do that! Are there any good re/sources for this topic? Also, with $Y_{p} = xAe^{2x}$ do we use the product rule for differentiation then? And, is there anything preventing me from trying something like $Y_{p} = x^{2}Ae^{2x}$? (i.e. when do I stop?)

Comment: @PizzAzzra I remember that trick from my times as student, hence I am sorry, but forgot the sources. You just differentiate as always (so yes, you should use the product rule). If you still get 0 as sum, continue with $x^{k+1}$ until you get something non-0. As far as I remember this should always happen at most with $k$ is number of summands/highest degree of differentiation (+1). I calculated it through with your example and $xe^{2x}$ should be fine.

Comment: If a guess ends up being part of your complementary solution, then the particular solution is found by multiplying by x until your guess is no longer a complementary solution.

You can prove this using reduction of order methods.

This also shows that multiplying by x again won't necessarily work, as reduction of order only works with complimentary solutions.

Comment: @Kaynex Thank you for that useful rule of thumb.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Notice the complementary solutions are:
$$y = C_1e^{x} + C_2e^{2x}$$
So, $y = Ae^{2x}$ is a homogeneous solution. Plugging that into the left side will result in zero. It can never result in $e^{2x}$, so it cannot be one of your particular solutions.
$$$$
If this ever happens, multiply your guess by x. The actual guess you should use is $Axe^{2x}$. Just in general, if you ever get a form where you cannot solve for your coefficients, you know your guess was incorrect.